# MYSQL add 2 hours to time in Database when echo to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried numerous ways to get this time zone issue resolved. I have a MYSQL database that stores Time in the following format.

2021-01-15 14:34:46

The time is uploaded by a tellematic device so I have no control over the time loaded to the DB

I need to add two ours to the time from the DB and echo it to a PHP Page

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM gs_objects WHERE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) > dt_tracker 
AND imei = '358899053810647'

<td><?php echo $rows['dt_tracker']; ?></td>
```

The time stays the same no change to it not adding the two hours

AND

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, '%Y-%m-%d '),
              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%m:%s'),
              DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, '')) AS dt_format, 
FROM gs_objects WHERE imei = '358899053810647'

<?php echo $rows['dt_format']; ?>
```

There is no output at all

dt_tracker is the date and time saved to the database the **DATATYPE** is **DATETIME**

I need to add two hours to the output time.

2021-01-15 16:34:46

**Resolved with the following Query:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, '%H:%i:%s '),
              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s'),
              DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, ' %p')) AS dt_tracker, imei FROM 
gs_objects WHERE imei = '358899053064062'
```

Comment: And what's the question about this? Anything not woroking as expected?

Comment: Sorry I saw I had half a statement and no question. I have corrected it now. In most queries I used there is no change to the time and shows the DB time

Comment: "I need to add" is still not a question - so what's the problem in adding the time?

Comment: When I echo the dt_tracker time it is not adding the 2 hours on the output. The tracking device is set to 0 Time Zone my platform is +2 Time zone so the output on the echo should add 2 hours to the DB time

Comment: The first query does not modify the returned value after all, as you select the values that are given in the database, and not the modified one. If the first query returns rows, but the second does not, what have you tried to debug this? After all, is this even related to PHP? Have you tried running the queries through something like phpMyAdmin, just to remove moving parts from the problem?

Comment: I have puzzled it out as you said @NicoHaase check your errors. I have added the correct code to the question and it updates the correct time now

Comment: I was trying to change the time with Date format in my first line time format in my second line. Thanks for pointing me back to errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, '%H:%i:%s '),
              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '%H:%i:%s'),
              DATE_FORMAT(dt_tracker, ' %p')) AS dt_tracker, imei FROM 
gs_objects WHERE imei = '358899053064062'
```

In my initial Query I was conflicting the Date format with the Time Format

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM gs_objects WHERE (NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR) > dt_tracker
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want. If you want the **output** value to be date-shifted (as it seems from your title), just add the date-shifted value at the end of the query with the same field name:

```
SELECT *, 
    DATE_ADD(dt_tracker, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS dt_tracker 
FROM gs_objects ...

<td><?php echo $rows['dt_tracker']; ?></td>
```

If you want to select the rows where the `dt_tracker` value is between a certain distance from `NOW()` - which is your second example - then just replace `dt_tracker` with the above `DATE_ADD` formula in the `WHERE` clause.